# How to block specific URL rather than the entire domain on a computer without software?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, connection, blocking

I've been doing some googling and I can't seem to find an answer. How do you block a specific URL rather than the entire website without using a software.

---

For example, I want to block `www.facebook.com/images/games/facebook_gaming_instant_game_banner.png`. So essentially, I can access everything on facebook, but for the link above.

I want to block it on my entire computer and not just on my browser. Meaning, if I have a program trying to access this URL, its still blocked. How can I do this?

I tried blocking it in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` using the code:

```
127.0.0.1    www.facebook.com/images/games/facebook_gaming_instant_game_banner.png
```

Comment: When it comes to preventing yourself from doing something, its better to learn self control, rather than a fix.  The reason is, if you implement something to prevent you from doing something, you have the ability to simply undo what you did.

Comment: You want to block access for all applications on the computer and don't want to use any software.  Does your router have a blacklist capability?  You've included conditions that restrict possible solutions.  Can you add some context as to why you need those restrictions?

Comment: @Keltari Actually, its not to do with self control. Its more of a programming/networking type thing. Facebook was just an example.

Comment: @fixer1234 My router? Like the physical plastic router I have?

Comment: @fixer1234 My router has parental controls but it doesn't let me block the exact url. Only the entire domain

Comment: Turning this into a software request makes it off-topic & also entirely changes the existing question, which has been adequately answered. I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not possible. To block an HTTP resource, you need a filter that understands HTTP. No such thing is built into Windows (or any other operating system).

Indeed, with HTTPS (which Facebook uses) you’d have to perform a MITM attack on the encrypted connection to filter its contents. Or, you know, just use a browser extension.

The `hosts` file is for *hosts* only. So you could put `www.facebook.com` there and it would work and block the main Facebook web page.

Comment: Since its not possible, is there any software recommendations to block outgoing requests for specific URL's?

Comment: Sure, uBlock Origin. It’s the best ad blocker there is.

Comment: This is for the browser... I wanted a program for the computer

Comment: Yes. That's not possible, because SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Block Site or browser Extensions. Currently I am using Block site and it is working fine.

Comment: Well I am looking for a solution to block it from my entire computer. Not just my browser (as written in my question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Cold Turkey. It is working for me. But, the problem with this is that if you are an expert then you can remove the software from your computer unless your account doesn't have the full privileges.